# Как определить текущее местоположение пользователя и что лучше использовать?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, геолокация

Есть интернациональный проект. При совершении пользователем определенных действий, необходимо получать данные о его местоположении (страна, город, улица(если возможно)), и после уже отсылаем эти данные на наш сервер. Я видел примеры от гугл и яндекс карт, там можно получить координаты. Я все же более склонен к использованию гугла.

Есть ли пример получения этих данных при этом сделав как можно меньше запросов?

P.S. При этом мне не нужно что-либо отрисовывать на карте и рисовать саму карту

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Силами HTML5 — `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`. Браузер спрашивает у пользователя разрешение и в случае согласия отдает ОЧЕНЬ (в большинстве случаев) точные данные в виде широты и долготы. Потом это можно скормить https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro без карты. 
    
   **upd 2018:** данный способ работает для `https`-сайтов
2. Определять по IP. Есть бесплатная (но не самая полная) база — https://dev.maxmind.com/ru/geolite2/ Вот есть библиотека под нее — https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php В этом случае данные доступны сразу, но они не точные (Страна, город).

Answer (score 2):

Если на js, могу дать совет воспользоваться запросом, 
на сторонний сервис, 
после чего получить json данные с него, через **jsonp**.

```
<!-- Answer stackoverflow -->
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<div id="details"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function (response) { 
      $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip); 
      $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region); 
      $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4)); 
      console.log(response); 
    }, "jsonp");
</script>
```

**На codepen:** 
https://codepen.io/AndreyMyP/pen/gzXVXV

Answer (score 1):

Яндекс, кстати, предоставляет "API Geocoder" для HTTP запросов: 
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/

Ответ геокодера может быть сформирован в следующих форматах:
XML, согласно спецификации YMapsML;
JSON или JSONP.

Чтобы начать работать с HTTP API Геокодера, нужно получить ключ для пакета «JavaScript API и HTTP Геокодер».

Но есть ограничение на кол-во бесплатных запросов 25тыс в сутки. И определенные условия, например проект должен находиться в открытом доступе, т.е. если есть регистрация, то она должна быть открыта для всех.